# Создание зависимостей между полями двух контент типов

Tags: drupal, relation

Есть два контент типа Регионы и Города, каждый регион включает в себя города и каждый город включает в себя регион, как сделать так что б при добавлении в регион города в нем автоматически проставлялся регион и наоборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помог вот этот модуль [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer),для роботы нужно проделать следующие шаги:

1. Создаем соответствующие контент типы
2. Создаем reference поля для каждого типа
3. Включаем модуль и настраиваем его здесь:Configuration >> System >> Corresponding entity references

Пробовал использовать [Corresponding node references](https://www.drupal.org/project/cnr), но в моем случае это не сработало